# Facebook Comments Plugin on webpage not working

Tags: html, facebook

There are comments on a webpage using the Facebook comments plugin, but I cannot see them. However, I can post my own comment logged in with Facebook.

The page has some kind of 'warning' about enabling an `href`?

Answer (score 0):

`href` is the URL link to where your comments are located and what your users are commenting on. You need this for the plugin to work for other users.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/),

> News feed stories on Facebook will link to this URL.

Replace `YOURURLHERE` with the URL for where you have the comments plugin.

`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="YOURURLHERE" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>`